# How to access only the exception error message in R

Tags: r, try-catch

I have successfully set up my first exception in R

In my function I have a nice `stop("Today the moon is blue. Can't continue.")`

And I now call it with

```
tryCatch( {
  XXX(yyy)
}, error = function(err) {
   system(paste('echo "',err,'" | mail -s "BLUE MOON" "xxx@yyy.com"',sep=""))
})
```

The problem is that the err message isn't `Today the moon is blue. Can't continue.`, but a whole mumble jumble in front of it, something along the lines of `Error in XXX(yyy) : Today the moon is blue. Can't continue.`

Except that `XXX` and `yyy` are rather involved and the output just becomes a mess.

How do I access only the error message I threw, without the stuff in front of it? And how would I find the answer myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 system(paste('echo "',err$message,'" | mail -s "BLUE MOON" "xxx@yyy.com"',sep=""))
```

A condition has a message and an internal `call` language object (how the error was triggered). To see all of it, try `print(str(err))`, which would have allowed you to deduce that `err$message` was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this. Based on this error message, you can catch it later and echo to console.

```
fun <- function(x) stop("Bad moon is rising.")
my.catch <- tryCatch(fun(x = 5), error = function(e) e)
my.catch
<simpleError in fun(x = 5): Bad moon is rising.>
if(grepl("Bad moon is rising.", my.catch)) system(...)
```